# Why marrying your cousins is allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

My question is - marrying your relatives leads to children having genetic problems.

Why is it halal for us if it's harmful?

One of the answer my brother gave me is - to increase population of Muslims at the start when we were few in number.

I want to know if there is any another reasoning behind this?

Comment: Allah has allowed us to marry cousins that's why it is allowed. That's it. A Muslim should not need a reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Amris Can you elaborate on why you believe that it is harmful to marry one's cousin?

Comment: @Ahmed It says it in the question